# Angular Material multi objects drag and drop with resizing problem

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop, resize

hi I stuck problem about programming drag and drop with resizing

dynamically add cdkDrag div by click add button
It works have only one div, but if I add more than 2 divs , When try to resize height of older div.other divs move followed by older div resizing. It's quite strange. Is it bug?

I tried all other stuff but failed.please check follow site and advice me.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vkxx3r

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

finally I solved. just change object postion relative to absolute. 
what an idoit I am.

Comment: Can you accept your own question so the issue is closed?

Comment: Is that your changes are added in slackblitz example?